# Understanding Radon-Nikodym derivative property.

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I'm trying to understanding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650110/radon-nikod%C3%BDm-chain-rule-and-other-properties) proof.

My problem is when he says that $\mu=\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\nu\quad (1)$.

By Radon-Nikodym, we have $\mu(E)=\int_{E}\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}d\nu$. How could the OP get it to the $(1)$ equation?

Looks like the OP suppose that $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ is constant, but is this true? Is OP correct?

Comment: $\mu = \frac{d\mu}{d \nu} \nu$ is an equality of *measures*. The point is that $\mu(E) = \int_{E} d\mu = \int_{E} \frac{d \mu}{d \nu} d \nu$ for every $E$. The right hand side is $\eta(E)$ where $\eta = \frac{d \mu}{d \nu} d \nu$, so $\mu = \eta$ because they are equal over every measurable set, and now $(1)$ follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $\mu= f\nu$ for some $\nu$-integrable or positive function $f$ conventionally means that $\mu(E)=\int_E f\textrm{d}\mu$. It's simply notation. Note that in the case where $f$ is constant, this *agrees* with the usual definition of a scaled measure, i.e. if $\mu=c\nu$, then $\mu(E)=c\nu(E)=\int_E c\textrm{d}\nu$.

Comment: So the OP question is not actually correct, right? Since he is using some notation tricks.

Comment: What he's doing looks completely fine to me. It *is* true that if $\mu=f \nu$ and $\nu=g\xi$, then $\mu=fg\xi$ with the above definition.

Comment: To clarify: The only trick happening is that we've chosen notation for densities that's suggestive of the multiplication of functions. However, that turns out to be *good* suggestive notation, since basically every computational identity that this seems to suggest turns out to be true (again, with the above definition).

Comment: Intuitively, I can see what are you saying, but I don't see how this is formal math.

I have the Radon-Nikodym statement: $\mu(E)=\int_E f\textrm{d}\mu$. This statement is right, with all parts formally defined. To understand it in a better a way, we write $\mu=\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\nu$, which is good to get an intuition, but it is not well defined, since $\mu$ is a function of $\mathcal{X}$ and the Radon-Nikodym is a function of $X$. And he uses this not formal form of Radon-Nikodym to prove what he wants.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean not well-defined? We've literally just defined what we mean, when we write $\mu=f \nu$. You're correct that it's *not* the pointwise multiplication of functions, but it's perfectly well-defined. All you have to check to carry on with his computation is that for any $\mu$-integrable $g$, we have $\int g\textrm{d}\mu=\int fg\textrm{d}\nu$ which follows from an elementary application of the standard machine (checking for indicators, getting simple functions by linearity, getting positive functions by monotone convergence, and then applying linearity to get $L^1$-functions).